# JavaScript / jQuery Countdown

Tags: javascript, countdown

What I'd like to accomplish is a countdown that updates live... like this:

6 Days (just the days)

12 Hours (just hours within 1 day)

59 Minutes (just minutes within 1 hour)

59 Seconds (just seconds within 1 minute)

Best way to accomplish this?

Comment: It's not so much a matter of what I've tried... I just wanted to see if there was a script floating around that would accomplish this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can find a working example at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/QH6X8/79/

```
var end = new Date('15 Dec 2010');

var _second = 1000;
var _minute = _second * 60;
var _hour = _minute * 60;
var _day = _hour *24

var timer;

function showRemaining()
{
    var now = new Date();
    var distance = end - now;
    if (distance < 0 ) {
       // handle expiry here..
       clearInterval( timer ); // stop the timer from continuing ..
       alert('Expired'); // alert a message that the timer has expired..
    }
    var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
    var hours = Math.floor( (distance % _day ) / _hour );
    var minutes = Math.floor( (distance % _hour) / _minute );
    var seconds = Math.floor( (distance % _minute) / _second );

    var countdownElement = document.getElementById('countdown');
    countdownElement.innerHTML = 'Days: ' + days + '<br />';
    countdownElement.innerHTML += 'Hours: ' + hours+ '<br />';
    countdownElement.innerHTML += 'Minutes: ' + minutes+ '<br />';
    countdownElement.innerHTML += 'Seconds: ' + seconds+ '<br />';
}

timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
```

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli if you want to display a message after the time expires how do you do that?

Comment: @sarsar, in the `showRemaining` method, check if the distance is negative. if it is then it has expired...

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli this code is exactly what i needed :D i dont know how long a searched for something so simple and easy to use. if i could bother you with one more thing. what would it take to add cookies so that if a user were to refresh it wouldnt start the timer all over again?

Answer (score 3):

[jQuery Countdown plugin](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html)

Comment: I'd like to avoid using a plugin if I can. a bit too heavy for what I need.

Comment: However, is there way to use this plugin in the mannor I'm asking? Only showing "days" when there's more than an entire day left, only showing "hours" when there's less than a day left, etc?

Answer (score 0):

here you can generate countdown timer if you like - just press generate and copy paste the results into .html file

http://www.ricocheting.com/code/javascript/html-generator/countdown-timer

Answer (score 0):

Notable mention: http://www.littlewebthings.com/projects/countdown/
(probable irrelevant since you mentioned that you don't want to use a plugin)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the above accepted approach is that there will be issues here related to timezone differences and daylight saving time.  See this question asked by me [Javascript Countdown and Timezone and Daylight Saving Time Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686903/javascript-countdown-and-timezone-and-daylight-saving-time-issues)

Answer (score 0):

[jCounter](http://devingredients.com/jcounter/) offers control on what format you want your countdown to display among other control settings and methods.